# Command AT to get balance of sim card

Tags: router, at-command, lte

I have a question, I want to know the balance that have my sim card using my modem, so I sent AT command to Claro Provider, When I sent at+cusd=1, it returns me ok but when I sent at+cusd+1,"*123#", it returns me cms error 305. I read many post that use that at command and it works but not for me and I do not understand

Answer (score 0):

Try this command, works for me.

```
at+cusd=1,"*123#",15
```